# CacheLite/Lite.php not found

Tags: stream, pear

> Warning: include_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   /data/web/virtuals/90412/virtual/www/_lib/CacheLite/Lite.php on line
>   537

My website is running perfectly on a free webhost company.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the CacheLite package from pear - available at http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite